# Get Android Device Accurate Position in Three Axis

Tags: android, position, accelerometer

I am trying to program an android app that I need to calculate the accurate position of the device every 5 seconds in the three axis and I made a lot of searches about this and did not find any thing. I found a lot of websites talks about accelerometer sensor  but I found that this solution does not give accurate position.  Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you mean with "his solution does not give accurate position"? What kind of output do you need?

Comment: i need the x,y,z coordinates of the device every 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [rotation sensor](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-rotate), they even provide an sample app in Android SDK, called RotationVectorDemo.
This sensor combines gyroscope + compass, and passes you already processed data.